# Calling window.close in IE throws null or object not found error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, outlook

I have a very wierd error cropping up in IE.

I am opening a window, with a specific url , and closing it immidiately, using the following code:

```
openSomething(guid)
{
   my_window = window.open("outlook:"+guid,"mywindow","width=0,height=0");
   my_window.close();
}
```

This script outputs things as expected, i.e this opens the right outlook mail needed, but IE window shows the error "my_window null or not an object".

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here??

Comment: @T.J : I simply forgot to add that in a hurry.I agree that I did a mistake.But I am pretty sure something as simple as this, shouldnt have triggerred a reaction like this from you.With respect, I certainly know how to format a question, things sometimes skip minds.I am sure you understand.Nonetheless, thanks Tim for editing.And T.J and answers for the question??

Comment: Sorry if that seemed over-the-top, it wasn't meant to be. Just meant to be clear and offer links. (I have them handy for newbies, you see.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually happens when the window is blocked by a/the popup blocker. You'll need to make sure that `window.open` actually returns a window:

```
my_window = window.open("outlook:"+guid,"mywindow","width=0,height=0");
if (my_window && my_window.close) {
  my_window.close();
}
```